# gradle dsl method not found 'uselibrary()'

Tags: android, android-studio

HttpClient is deprecated in target 23, So still I want use httpClient in my project therefore I have added following dependency org.apache.http.legacy in gradle file, after rebuild the project, I am getting following error.

> Error:(6, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'useLibrary()' Possible
>   causes:
>
> The project 'Development' may be using a version of
>   Gradle that does not contain the method. Gradle settings
>
> The build file
>   may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply
>   Gradle plugin

My gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.mobile.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions{
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('FlurryAnalytics-5.5.0.jar')
    compile files('HockeySDK-3.5.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.+'
}
```

**root build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also post your top-level `build.gradle` file, the one that you will find in your project root.

Comment: Added please have a look now

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

Comment: Also 1.3.1, the last stable version.

Comment: Also 1.5.0, the current version